# GAS Advanced Slides API batchUpdate updateParagraphStyle

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I cannot find the Google documentation for updateParagraphStyle in batchUpdate.

I am attempting to align text in text boxes in slides. The horizontal and vertical alignments seem to be indifferent places. Horizontal is part of the paragraph styling? I have read the entries for documents and sheets also looking for the correct syntax. I don't want anyone to write my code. I just want to find the documentation.

My guess for vertical alignment within shape:

```
updateShapeProperties': {
     ,"shapeProperties": {
        "contentAlignment": 'MIDDLE'  // TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM
```

My guess for horizontal alignment within shape:

```
updateShapeProperties
   'updateParagraphStyle': {
        'style': {
          "alignment":   // CENTER, START, END, JUSTIFIED
```

My best guesses above. I never found paragraph style in slides documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

**Vertical Alignment** can be set using [UpdateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest) -> [ShapeProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#shapeproperties) -> `contentAlignment`

**Horizontal Alignment** can be set using [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateparagraphstylerequest) -> [ParagraphStyle](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/text#paragraphstyle) -> `alignment`

---

**References:**

- [Changing paragraph formatting](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/styling#changing_paragraph_formatting)
- [Updating text style](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/text#updating_text_style)
- [Updating paragraph style](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/text#updating_paragraph_style)

Comment: Thank you. It is to bad this information is not repeated in the slides documentation.